# Objective C HTTPS request failing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, https

I am fairly new to Objective C, and even newer to the network API's such as NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLSession. Anyways, I have a problem calling calling an asynchronous API to POST to an HTTPS address and get a JSON packet of data back:

I can call curl from the command line and successfully get a packet of data like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"foo","pass":"bar"}' --insecure https://bla bla bla.com/xxxx
```

and get a json packet in response to curl:

```
"{'key1':'val1','key2':'val2','key3':'val3'}
```

I want to do the equivalent in Objective C. 
This is what I have so far:

```
#define USER_URI @"https://bla bla bla.com"
    NSDictionary* gistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              username, @"name",
                              password, @"pass", nil];
    NSError* jsonError;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:gistDict options: NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error: &jsonError];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: USER_URI]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    NSURLSession* session      = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler: ^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        BOOL success = data && httpResponse.statusCode == 200;

        if (success) {
            NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: nil];
            NSLog(@"json dict %@", jsonDictionary);
        } 
    }];
```

The problem is at runtime: data is 0 bytes and response is nil. The block parameter `error` returns a message stating:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
```

Is this because I'm posting to an HTTPS url and not an HTTP url?

Comment: Is the https certificate signed by a CA in the Keychain? You can check what is actually being sent and received with Carles Proxy, it works with SSL. Have you NSLog()'ed jsonData and is it good?

Comment: Hi, I have no idea what 'CA' is. But when I NSLog'd my jsonData, it got this: JSON Data = <7b0a2020 226e616d 6522203a 20227465 7374222c 0a202022 70617373 22203a20 22746573 74220a7d> which isn't so helpful I think.

Comment: CA is Certificate Authority, who signed your SSL certificate, a CA or self-signed? As for the `jsonData`, the main point is that it isn't nil.

Comment: I don't have any more information about the CA. I would have to check with someone else for more information about that.